# Default values [anomaly] for function parameter

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I came across something I don't quite understand with how the parameters in the def function works:

ie:

```
def test(a=1, b=9, c='what'):
    return a

test(a,b,c)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-295-937fe43dbbd5> in <module>()
      2     return a
      3 
----> 4 test(a,b,c)

NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

and

```
def test(a=1, b=9, c='what'):
    return a

test('what')

Output: 'what'
```

Well, I am looking to set the parameters a,b as default values. Now, for the 1st example, if I call test(a,b,c), it says a is not defined. However, I have already "defined" it in the function parameter? That means, if let's say a, b and c are default parameters, I cannot execute test(a,b,c)? Only test() works? WHAT!

In example 2, I don't even know anymore...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to call your method test with three variables which do not exist in the global scope where you are running the method.

The way you are defining your method:

```
def test(a=1, b=1, c=1)
```

does not imply that the arguments `a, b, c` are available to be used globally the way you are trying to use them.

By defining your method as `a=1, b=1, c=1`, you are setting *default values* to your arguments. What this means, is that you can call your method with or without passing arguments to your method.

So, for your first example, you can call it like this:

```
test(a="what")
```

Which indicates that now you are assigning "what" to `a` and will no longer hold its default value of "1".

Alternatively, you can simply call it without any arguments, which in turn would assign default values to your local arguments inside your method. So, if you actually call your method like this:

```
test()
```

Then, the default value of "1" will now be assigned to "a".

In your second example, you are passing a string, and by default, your parameters get assigned from left to right of your function definition. So, when you do this:

```
test("what")
```

You are assigning "what" to `a`.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. So, what does it exactly mean when they say 'default parameters'. Does that mean I have to declare a,b,c as a global variable instead of assigning a=1, b=9, c='whatever' in the function?

Comment: @misheekoh Not quite. I will add to my answer to explain that part.

Comment: You might want to try googling "scope resolution in python". In short, when you enter a function, you enter a new scope where a, b, and c are defined because of the default arguments. When you're calling the function,  you're outside of that scope and those variables don't exist yet.

Comment: Your explanation mixes up keyword arguments and default argument values. While the syntax for a default value looks like the syntax for a keyword argument, they have nothing to do with each other. Defining a default of `a=1` has no bearing on whether you can or must provide the argument by keyword when you call the function.

Comment: @user2357112 You are absolutely right. I used the wrong terminology. I will change the answer to reflect this. Thanks for bringing it up.

Comment: @user2357112 I made a quick change to fix the major error in the answer. I'm going to further review it and make it clearer. Thanks again. Let me know if there is anything else glaringly terrible in there.

Comment: @idjaw: Well, you've still got some parts where you're implying that you need to use keyword arguments ("you will actually have to call it like this").

Comment: @idjaw thank you again for the clarification. Just to clarify by default parameters/arguments, what they are saying is that I can call the function test() without having to define a,b,c again and that test() should be able to do whatever with the values of a, b, and c defined as global variables

Comment: @misheekoh: They're local variables, not globals.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks again, really appreciate the review. I *refactored* my answer again. Feel free to send some more constructive criticism.

Comment: @misheekoh as user2357112, when you define a method foo(a,b,c). The arguments `a,b,c` are local to that method. They are not globally available at all.